# Retrieve real time data from interactive broker using API

Tags: python, interactive-brokers

Good morning,

I have an issue with retrieving realtime data of VIX futures. No issues for indexes or ETFs. I use the code below but it does not work. Can anyone help please? BR, Vittorio

```
# Get VIX M1 #added 3/30/2023
try: 
 VIX_CELL_M1='D58'

 class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
  def __init__(self):
    EClient.__init__(self, self)
    self.data = []

  def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
     if tickType == 4:  # Last Price
        self.data.append([datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S"), price])

 def run_loop():
   app.run()

 app = IBapi()
 app.connect("127.0.0.1", 7496, 123)

 contract = Contract()
 contract.symbol = "VXJ3"
 contract.secType = "FUT"
 contract.exchange = "CFE"
 contract.currency = "USD"
 contract.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "20230418"

 app.reqMarketDataType(3)
 latest_vix_price_M1=app.reqMktData(1, contract, "", False, False, [])

 print(latest_vix_price_M1)
```

The output of the code was "none". I was expecting a value.

Comment: The indentation isn't probably in run_loop() function.

Comment: The title says real time data, but reqMarketDataType(3) is setting the request to delayed data.  Which are you trying to retrieve?

Answer (score 0):

2 possible issues, either the contract is invalid (in that case you should get a 200 error) and/or you're not subscribed to the data.

Note below, details from a retrieved contract.

```
Symbol=VIX       <----
LocalSymbol=VXJ3
ConId=575645606
SecType=FUT
PrimaryExch=CFE
lastTradeDateOrContractMonth=20230419    <----
```

You can check the first case with reqContractDetails, and you can check the second by loading the contract in a TWS chart (VIX as symbol, then select futures).

I believe (but have not verified) the required data subscription is Level1/CFE Enhanced

Answer (score 0):

I came here due to the similar issue when searching on-line. The way how IB works is quite bizarre.

When you claim

```py
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)
        self.data = [] #Initialize variable to store candle

    def historicalData(self, reqId, bar):
        print(f'Time: {bar.date} Close: {bar.close}')
        self.data.append([bar.date, bar.close])
```

The data should be called like this later.

```py
#Working with Pandas DataFrames

import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(app.data, columns=['DateTime', 'Close'])
df['DateTime'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['DateTime'],unit='s')
```

The example is shown [here](https://algotrading101.com/learn/interactive-brokers-python-api-native-guide/)

I understand what you are doing, the way how IB API handle this looks like very unprofessional to me. I haven't figure out why

```py
self.data
```

is later mapped toward

```py
app.data
```

Something not consistent happened inside this API.